# Is JRN financial solutions a SCAM?

Tags: fraud

JRN Financial Solutions, i have been applying for Jobs online and got a random mail offering me a personal assistant role! Is it safe to go ahead with this?

Comment: I don't think the answer to the "is this a scam" question has ever been "no"

Comment: Rofl!  Very true!

Comment: @Rocky(+) bzzt! https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2542/have-there-been-any-is-this-a-scam-questions-that-the-answer-was-no

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is this a money laundering scam?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/100035/is-this-a-money-laundering-scam)

Comment: If you [look at their site](https://jrnfinancialsolutions.com/) it is not as bad as some, but it has enough typos, and is written in such a non-technical style that it should be a red flag.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds very similar to other postings on this issue.

Sounds like a scam.  Run.

Comment: This is basically just another pointer to the dupe. I don't think there's any reason to put it in an answer too.

Comment: There are 3 on this same issue/company.  I already flagged it as a dupe too.

Comment: Yep, that's great. There's just no reason to also put it in an answer.

Comment: Edited.  Thanks!